# Как исправить ошибку в цикле foreach, PHP?

Tags: php, foreach

Хотя сайт работает нормально, в логах сервера регулярно появляется ошибка:

> PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /...путь на
>   сервере../файл.php on line 9

Вот эта строка:

```
foreach($_SESSION['basket']["offers"] as &$offer)
```

Как правильно организовать цикл `foreach` в данном случае?

Comment: Перед вызовом цыкла проверяеться `if(!empty($_SESSION['basket']["offers"]))` ?

Comment: ок, Я использовал конструкцию    if(!empty($_SESSION['basket']["offers"])){foreach($_SESSION['basket']["offers"] as &$offer){...}} о на это выдается ошибка PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant php - assumed 'php' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Comment: Зачем косвенная адресация «&»?

Comment: MAX, хорошй вопрос)) писал код не я. Дываете в нем дело? и что значит "косвенная адресация"?

Comment: Косвенная - это по адресация ссылке (извиняюсь, это из «старой» школы в торопях написал). Вы проверьте существование isset($_SESSION['basket']["offers"]), после уберите символ «&». Дальше нужно по коду посмотреть, но вы сможете «&» использовать уже в теле цикла.

Answer (score 0):

Помогла эта проверка

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['basket']["offers"]))
```

спасибо [Дмитрию Мирошниченко](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/240971/%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE)